# Zathura refreshes faster when Skim is also on

Tags: macos, zathura

I am on a M2 Macbook and this problem is in the context of using vimtex and zathura.

I am using zathura to preview documents generated via vimtex, however, there is a slight delay between the compile time and the time zathura reloads. Because of that I looked for for other viwers, such as Skim. Turning on the auto reload for it, it does reload the second the file is changed, all good.

The issue is that when I tried to compare them they are both the same speed. Zathura's reload becomes faster when there is a Skim instance open viewing the same file.

This gives me hope that I can get zathura to reload properly.

Does anybody know what is going on/ how to exploit this?